# jquery animate hide the scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, overflow

i have a little issue animeting a `div` that is `overflowed`, the scroll blink during animation.

i made a fast example:

```
$(".div-animate").on("click", function(e){
    var toTop = 100,
        toHeight = $(this).outerWidth(true) + toTop;

    $(this).animate({
        top: toTop,
        height: toHeight
    });
});
```

[**live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJhYF/24/)

how can i prevent this little 'scroll blink' ?

Comment: it depends on scrollbar i think, anyway on macosx and FF the scroll doesn't blinks

Comment: on my chrome and FF, blinks happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery adds an overflow:hidden rule when use animate function.
There are two hacks you can do:

1) Modify the line of the jQuery source where overflow is setted to hidden (you can do this only if you import jquery from your site)

2) Force the property in your css doing something like this

```
.div-animate {
     overflow: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: damn, why i diding try this before ask, anyway thanks, will check the js line.

Answer (score 2):

Well this can be done this way too:

```
$(this).animate({
        top: toTop,
        height: toHeight
    }).css({"overflow":"auto"});
```

Comment: this is a clever way so that you don't have to use an !important tag in your css. good solution!